# How to search with querySelector for html-elements that have no id set in the source?

Tags: javascript, selectors-api, queryselector

Is this possible with querySelector?

This doesn't work, but gives simply all elements

```
document.querySelectorAll('*:not([id=""])');
```

More info: The user can enter his selector into an input field, and it would be nice if such a search for missing id would be possible without using additional checkboxes or settings, but just with the query-selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead use

```
document.querySelectorAll(':not([id])');
```

Comment: without a selector before `:`, `document.querySelectorAll(':not([id])');` selects all elements regardless of id status in the snippet tool here (try). `document.querySelectorAll('div:not([id])');` works as expected for divs without ids and similar can be used for other elements. Also, if the id attribute is present but set empty `id=""`, that solution treats it as having an id.